# question about making models in sqlalchemy

Tags: database, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm confused whether to use relationship or ForeignKey for each class.

I'm making models like:

```
class Map(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    map_name = db.Column(db.String(200))

class Mob(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    mob_name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    level = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

something like this.

for each map, there can be a few different mobs.
And one mob can be in each map

Answer (score 0):

**Foreign key (FK)**
is a column in the database, and has itself nothing to do with ORM.

**Relationship**
is an ORM thing, which helps in the manipulation of objects/data.

It's shown in [official documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html).

A assume you want to have one (Map) to many (Mobs) relationship.
In this case, you will probably want:

- Mob has Mob.map_id FK
  `map_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('maps.id'))`
- Map has a relationship to Mobs, accessible as attribute Map.mobs [list of Mob objects]
  `mobs = relationship("Mob")`
- Mob has a relationship to Map, accessible as attribute Mob.map [Map object]
  simplest way is to change code from answer above to
  `mobs = relationship("Mob", back_populates="map")`